# php-get data from form through get method

Tags: php

```
test.php?t=xxx,y=sss
```

This is how the user inputs data to my script.

How can I get this data as an array inside test.php, and remove the commas?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show your code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$temp = explode(',', $_GET['t']);
$t = $temp[0];
$y = substr($temp[1],2);
```

will get you what you want from the url you gave, however @Tudor Constantin has the best solution.

**Edit**

This will loop through all however many fields you have. They will finish up in $result in the correct order.

```
$temp = explode(',', $_GET['t']);
foreach($temp as $var){
    if(strpos($var, '=')){
        $exp = explode('=', $var);
        $result[] = $exp[1];
    } else $result[] = $var;
}
```

then var_dump $result gives this result

```
array
    0 => string 'xxx' (length=3)
    1 => string 'sss' (length=3)
    2 => string 'ttt' (length=3)
    3 => string 'uuu' (length=3)
```

**Edit 2**
Or you could try this:-

Say URL is "test.php?t=xxx,y=sss,z=ttt,a=uuu"

```
$temp = explode(',', $_GET['t']);
$key = array_keys($_GET);
$temp = array_reverse($temp);
$result[$key[0]] = array_pop($temp);
array_reverse($temp);
foreach($temp as $var){
    $exp = explode('=', $var);
    $result[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
}
```

Then var_dump($result); will give you:-

```
array
 't' => string 'xxx' (length=3)
 'a' => string 'uuu' (length=3)
 'z' => string 'ttt' (length=3)
 'y' => string 'sss' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

By accessing `$_GET['t']`, you will get the value `'xxx,y=sss'` - I think you have to change the URL to something like

```
test.php?t=xxx&y=sss
```

So you will be able to access `$_GET['t']` and get the value `'xxx'` and `$_GET['y']` having value `'sss'`

You could also send all the parameter values to one variable, separated by `'|'` for example - then split by that char:

URL would be `test.php?array=xxx|sss|ddd|rrr` and in `test.php` you will do:

```
$arr = explode('|', $_GET['array']);
```

This way in the `$arr` variable you will have an array of the values sent (no matter how many are there)

Comment: Constantin:may be i can strip commas.How do i do this and need to get into an array.

Comment: you can use explode: `$arr = explode(',', $_GET['t'])`

Comment: Constantin:I have 10 fields.How do i get y=sss.Can you post me snippet.

Comment: Constantin:I have 10 fields.How do i get y=sss.Can you post me snippet.t and y are variables.I need to post in to db.

Comment: Can you change the format of the URL? so we can think of a better method to pass the params

Comment: I edited my answer with sample format and the code to get the values in an array

Comment: @Constantin:How to send to insert query.Correct value to correct field.

Comment: I think you've lost me now - do you need the values to be in an array or in different variables? - $arr[0], $arr[1], etc, or in $t, $y, etc?